# How does the named pipe works in windows?

Tags: c++, operating-system, pipe, ipc

I was digging through the IPC mechanism in windows and tried to understand how does it work internally. When it comes to pipe(named pipe) i didn't find any concrete answer so far.

As filemapping uses files(internally) to share data and the address of the file is mapped to each process address as pointer and processes can use pointer to read/write to file.

In the similar way can someone help me out to understand how does the pipe works internally? Who holds the data between pipe server and pipe client?

Comment: Here is a [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx) on named pipes.

Comment: Thanks Raw N. I already went through this link and it has explained about APIs and how to use Pipes but i am looking for its internal procedure.

Comment: I can't understand the question, the kernel manages data and hold it until someone else will read it. Just like a regular file system, a file is a completely abstract object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is stored and managed in internal kernel buffer, which is released when all the handles to pipe is closed. It can expand and shrink during the process of communication. Additionally, because of communication ability across the network, there can be few buffers on server and client side. More on that you can read in Russinovich's **Windows Internals** (unfortunately can't say exactly where to read).